# $-7\cos(x) + 24\sin(x) = -25\sin(x - 16.26..) Why?$

Tags: trigonometry

Im confused as to why the $x$ angle is $-16.26..$ and not $360-16.26$ as well as why its $-25$ and not $25$?

I dont understand why its $-25sin(x-16.26..)$ and not $25sin(x+343.74..)$

Can someone please help me! thank you.

Comment: Try rewriting the right-hand side with a compound angle formula.

Comment: As an aside, if you plan on doing any math beyond an introductory highschool level you should get in the habit of using radians rather than degrees as there are numerous benefits to doing so.  That being said, $\sin(360^\circ + \alpha) = \sin(\alpha)$ so $\sin(x-16.26^\circ) = \sin(x+343.74^\circ)$ so it doesn't matter which of those you use since they are equal.  Remember that trig functions are periodic.  Now, the only thing remaining you seem to be confused by is the sign of the coefficient $25$.  Check your formula and arithmetic.

Comment: @JMoravitz Im in university, the question I was doing required me to write it in degrees, so sorry for doing so.I know my error now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-rcostheta-alpha-2009-1.pdf). I found this paper that explains why this method works, but I will try and summarize.
This formula is derived from the trig identity $$\cos(x-\alpha) = \cos(x)\cos(\alpha) + \sin(x)\sin(\alpha)$$
Basically,
$$R\cos(x-\alpha) = R\cos(x)\cos(\alpha) + R\sin(x)\sin(\alpha)$$
This means for an equation $b\sin(x)+a\cos(x)$,
$$a = R\cos(\alpha)$$ 
and
$$b = R\sin(\alpha)$$
Additionally, $a^2+b^2 = R^2(\cos^2(\alpha) + \sin^2(\alpha)) = R^2$, which means $R = \pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Moreover, $$\frac{b}{a} = \frac{R\sin(\alpha)}{R\cos(\alpha)} = \tan(\alpha)$$
This means $\alpha = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$. Thus, your equation can be simplified.
$$-7\sin(x) + 24\cos(x) = -\sqrt{7^2+24^2}\cos(x-\tan^{-1}(\frac{-24}{7})) = -25\cos(x+1.28700221759\ldots)$$
$\cos(x) = \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2})$ implies the following.\
$$-7\sin(x) + 24\cos(x) =-25\sin(x+1.28700221759\ldots + \frac{(4n-3)\pi}{2})$$
When $n$ is $-2$ you get the equation you had above.

Comment: So does this mean I have to do in cos and then convert it into sin? is there no alternative method?

Comment: There might be. I would have to look more into it though, but this method works.

Comment: Use $R\sin(x-\alpha) = R\sin(x) \cos(\alpha)-R\cos(x) \sin(\alpha)$ to get the result directly.

Comment: I realised where my error was! thanks so much. I made a mistake when it came to the angle of tan and didnt place it in the right 'quadrant'

Answer (score 1):

It follows directly from the identity

$$\sin(x-\theta)=\sin x\cos\theta-\cos x\sin\theta$$

$$-25\sin(x-\theta)=-7\cos x+24\sin x\iff\sin(x-\theta)=-\frac{24}{25}\sin x+\frac7{25}\cos x$$

Let $\theta$ be some angle such that

$$\begin{cases}\cos\theta=-\frac{24}{25}\\[1ex]\sin\theta=\frac7{25}\end{cases}$$

Then

$$\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=-\frac7{24}\implies\theta=\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac7{24}\right)+n\pi\approx(-16.26+360n)^\circ$$

where $n$ is any integer.